# JavaFX Scene Builder Expand ScrollPane area at runtime when adding components to attached AnchorPane

Tags: user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

I haven't been able to find info on this, but I've created a layout in Scene Builder, and I've placed an AnchorPane inside an empty ScrollPane, and added text, a slider, and a label in rows, and then added a button for the user to add a new entry of the above.

Basically a typical preference elicitation UI where the user can also add new entries and specify their own preference values as well.

When pressed, for testing purposes, the button creates a new label, adds it to the AnchorPane, and relocates it to a Y position outside the AnchorPane, and then resizes the AnchorPane so that the new label is included. 
The problem that I'm having is that the ScrollPane doesn't adjust and expand the scrollable area to fit the new AnchorPane height, so I can't scroll down to where the new label is visible. In Scene Builder, on the other hand, if I resize the AnchorPane so that it's larger than the ScrollPane, the latter dynamically adjusts the scrollable area, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
As requested, below is a minimally reproducible version of the project.

Class that loads the FXML and creates the scene

```
package main;
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Registration_Page extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    private TitledPane mainLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        showMainView();
    }

    private void showMainView() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Registration_Page.class.getResource("resources/Registration_Page.fxml"));
        mainLayout = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Class that acts as the button controller, using FXML-defined components.

```
package main;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;


public class ButtonController { 

    @FXML
    private Button plus;    

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane prefValuesAnchorPane;

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;

    @FXML
    protected void plusAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Label lbl1 = new Label("Hello");
        prefValuesAnchorPane.getChildren().add(lbl1);
        lbl1.relocate(18, 250);
        System.out.println(prefValuesAnchorPane.getHeight());
        System.out.println(lbl1.getLayoutY());
        if (lbl1.getLayoutY() >= prefValuesAnchorPane.getHeight())
        {
            prefValuesAnchorPane.resize(prefValuesAnchorPane.getWidth(), lbl1.getLayoutY() + 3);

        }
    }
}
```

The FXML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<TitledPane animated="false" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" text="User Registration" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="main.ButtonController">
  <content>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="52.0" layoutY="79.0" />
            <Text layoutX="14.0" layoutY="96.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Name" />
            <Text layoutX="14.0" layoutY="130.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Preference Values">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="137.0" prefHeight="223.0" prefWidth="332.0">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane fx:id="prefValuesAnchorPane" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="217.0" prefWidth="329.0">
                     <children>
                        <Text layoutX="15.0" layoutY="30.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Val1:" />
                        <Slider blockIncrement="1.0" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="15.0" majorTickUnit="1.0" max="10.0" minorTickCount="0" prefWidth="140.0" showTickLabels="true" snapToPixel="false" snapToTicks="true" />
                        <Label layoutX="280.0" layoutY="12.0" text="0">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Text layoutX="15.0" layoutY="62.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Val2:" />
                        <Slider blockIncrement="1.0" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="50.0" majorTickUnit="1.0" max="10.0" minorTickCount="0" prefWidth="140.0" showTickLabels="true" snapToTicks="true" />
                        <Label layoutX="280.0" layoutY="48.0" text="0">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Text layoutX="15.0" layoutY="97.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Val3:" />
                        <Slider blockIncrement="1.0" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="85.0" majorTickUnit="1.0" max="10.0" minorTickCount="0" prefWidth="140.0" showTickLabels="true" snapToTicks="true" />
                        <Label layoutX="280.0" layoutY="82.0" text="0">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Text layoutX="15.0" layoutY="133.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Val4:" />
                        <Slider blockIncrement="1.0" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="120.0" majorTickUnit="1.0" max="10.0" minorTickCount="0" prefWidth="140.0" showTickLabels="true" snapToTicks="true" />
                        <Label layoutX="280.0" layoutY="118.0" text="0">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Button fx:id="plus" graphicTextGap="1.0" layoutX="289.0" layoutY="153.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#plusAction" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="30.0" text="+" textAlignment="CENTER" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS" AnchorPane.topAnchor="153.0">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
            <Button layoutX="532.0" layoutY="335.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Next" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
  </content>
</TitledPane>
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to resize the `AnchorPane` yourself, assuming you use the proper constraints. If the `AnchorPane` isn't allowed to grow, things are different though. Please post a [mcve]. (This includes at least parts of your fxml.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to instead have a ScrollPane containing an AnchorPane (as it was), and for every entry added, create an AnchorPane or BorderPane or any other container pane (afaik), and add whatever to it, rather than adding components such as buttons or labels directly onto the original AP that's attached to the SP.